# Performing a double divide in sql

Tags: sql, syntax-error, divide

I am trying to double divide but I am getting no results.

The following is an example:

```
6.82 / (X/NULLIF (Y,0))
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please identify which form of `SQL` you are using (such as `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.) with another tag on your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
6.82 / (X / ISNULL(Y,0))
```

This will throw a divide by zero error when `Y` is `NULL` or `0`.  You can introduce conditional logic to handle such error.

Comment: What about when `X` is `0`?

Comment: It would improve this answer if you gave an example of such logic or another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If `Y` is `NULL` or `0` then your denominator will equate to -

```
( X / 0 )
```

This should result in a division by `0` error.

This potential for error can be corrected by rewriting your overall expression as -

```
( 6.82 * COALESCE( Y, 0 ) ) / X
```

The `COALESCE()` function shall return the first non-`NULL` argument it encounters, thus in this case if `Y` is null it will return `0`, otherwise it will return `Y`.

Similarly, if `X` is equal to `0` then a division by `0` error should occur.  How you should avoid this depends on the context of this problem, which you have not identified.  Thus I can not suggest how to handle this situation.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Further Reading**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce (on MySQL's `COALESCE()` function

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but i have tried the equation  - X / NULLIF (Y,0) and that is giving me results and thus x is not zero at all, the no results happen when i want to perform the mentioned equation. Is the double division possible at all?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it is not.  That sort of operation is fairly basic by maths standards, and should be in the capabilities of most languages.  I can't say for certain, though, as you have not identified which language you are using (as per my Comment on the Question).  If you can tell me that I can perform some research and hopefully figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for your help its MySql, sorry first time here.

Comment: No worries.  I'll look into it tomorrow morning (it's 2346 at the moment).  In the meantime I suggest editing your Question to add a *tag* for `MySQL`.

Comment: Pls let me know if you were able to get any sense out of my equation :)

Comment: I have updated my Answer so that your formula now uses the `COALESCE()` function.  I recommend you read the article on the function I have included a link to.  Please feel free to get back to me with any questions.